# Ngrx can't access state properties?

Tags: angular, typescript, store

I'm following the tutorial on the ngrx website to create a store / state, but I can't access the state properties:

auth.ts

```
export interface Auth{
    email: string;
    token: string;
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
}
```

auth.actions.ts

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import {Auth} from '../../models/auth';


export const authenticateUser = createAction('[Login Component] Authtenticate User', props<{payload: Auth}>());
export const logoutUser = createAction('[Navbar Component] Logout User');
```

auth.reducer.ts

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as AuthActions from '../actions/auth.actions';

export interface State {
  email: string;
  token: string;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

export const initialState: State = {
    email: 'test@test',
    token: '',
    isLoggedIn: false
}

const _authReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(AuthActions.authenticateUser, (state, { payload }) => ({
        email: payload.email,
        token: payload.token,
        isLoggedIn: payload.isLoggedIn,
    })),
    on(AuthActions.logoutUser, state => ({
        email: '',
        token: '',
        isLoggedIn: false,
    }))
)

export function authReducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
    return _authReducer(state, action);
  }
```

In my app.module.ts i'm importing

```
...
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import {authReducer} from './store/reducers/auth.reducer';

imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot({ auth: authReducer }),
  ],
```

And i have a navbar component where i want to show the user email, but when i try to access {{auth.email}} in html i get an error:
"Identifier 'email' is not defined. 'Observable' does not contain such a memberng".
navbar.component.ts

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Auth } from './../models/auth';

...

auth: Observable<Auth>;

constructor(private store: Store<{auth :Auth}>) {
    this.auth = store.select('auth');
}
```

Comment: You need some selectors maybe..?

Comment: maybe, but i found a solution...
store.select('auth').subscribe(x =>
      this.auth = x);